# Filtering a table stored in a variable

Tags: powershell

I have created a script that gathers a list of all accounts at are locked in a OU ands adds a column with row numbers. Using "-outvariable LockedUsersTable" the table is written to the variable. The table looks like this...

```
Row Name            samAccountName PasswordExpired Domain
--- ----            -------------- --------------- ------
  1 User A          usernameA                 True ABC
  2 User B          usernameB                False ABC
  3 User C          usernameC                 True ABC
  4 User D          usernameD                 True ABC
  5 User E          usernameE                 True ABC
```

My script then asks the user for the row that they would like to unlock, which sets the $ElectedUserRow variable.

This was my best guess at the solution but it doesn't work

```
$LockedUsersTable | -filter { $_.Row -eq $ElectedUserRow } | Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $_.samAccountName
```

Any help is a appreciated!

P.s. For those interested in why this script exists, I plan to use to generate and close a service now tickets. Then plan to use the learnt lessons for other admin tasks

Edit: Here is the code I use to generate the table and request user input

```
$RowNumber = 1
$Domain = ABC
$OU = "OU=Users,OU=Production,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com"
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -Searchbase $OU | ForEach-Object {New-Object psObject -Property @{'Row'=$RowNumber;'Name'= $_.Name; 'samAccountName' = $_.samAccountName;'Domain'=$Domain; 'PasswordExpired' = $_.PasswordExpired};$RowNumber ++} | Format-Table Row,Name,samAccountName,PasswordExpired,Domain -Autosize -outvariable LockedUsersTable

$ElectedUserRow = Read-Host "Enter the row number you would like to unlock"
```

### The resulting code from answer, Thanks  to Doug

```
# Displays locked users and Adds the select column
$RowNumber = 1
$Domain = ABC
$OU = "OU=Users,OU=Production,DC=corp,DC=ABC,DC=com,DC=au"
Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -Searchbase $OU | ForEach-Object {New-Object psObject -Property @{'Row'=$RowNumber;'Name'= $_.Name; 'samAccountName' = $_.samAccountName;'Domain'=$Domain; 'PasswordExpired' = $_.PasswordExpired};$RowNumber ++} | Select-Object -Property Row,Name,samAccountName,PasswordExpired,Domain -outvariable LockedUsersTable | Format-Table -Autosize

$ElectedUserRow = Read-Host "Enter the row number you would like to unlock"
$RowNumber = 1

# Use row number to as item to unlock
$LockedUsersTable | Where-Object { $_.Row -eq $ElectedUserRow } | Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $_.samAccountName
```

Comment: Replace `-filter` with `Where-Object`

Comment: Format-Table is converting your table into something that isn't very useful (except for displaying).  What you want is an array of PSCustomObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without showing us how you populate `$ElectedUserRow`, we would all be guessing. However, might I suggest using `Out-GridView` for a friendly user interface and for passing along the selected user?

```
$LockedUsersTable |
    Out-GridView -Title "Please select the user to unlock" -OutputMode Single |
        Unlock-ADAccount -Identity $_.samAccountName -WhatIf
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll give it a go. here is what I'm using... $ElectedUserRow = Read-Host "Enter the row number you would like to unlock"

Comment: Out-GridView Error:... Out-GridView : Data format not supported in Out-GridView.
At line:2 char:5
+     Out-GridView -Title "Please select the user to unlock" -OutputMode Single |
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [Out-GridView], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DataNotQualifiedForGridView,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutGridViewCommand

Comment: Remove format table. You can change it to select-object